# How can I add smooth transitions during page navigation in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm developing a Flutter application and I want to incorporate smooth transitions when navigating between screens. Currently, the transition is instant, which doesn't provide a visually pleasing experience for my users.

What are the recommended approaches or techniques to implement smooth page transitions in Flutter? I'm primarily using Flutter's built-in widgets and framework for my development.

I've heard about Hero animations and PageRoute transitions in Flutter, but I'm not sure how to use them effectively to achieve the desired smooth transition effect. Are there any specific libraries or packages that can assist in creating these transitions? It would be helpful if you could provide some code examples or point me to relevant resources.

Additionally, I want to ensure that the transitions work seamlessly on both Android and iOS devices. Any guidance on cross-platform compatibility would be appreciated.

Comment: I'd like to know more about this too...

Comment: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/animation/page-route-animation

Answer (score 0):

Check out go_router package https://pub.dev/packages/go_router. Example below

Main file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';
import 'magic_string.dart';
import 'route.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

var router = RouteGenerator().router;

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      routeInformationParser: router.routeInformationParser,
      routerDelegate: router.routerDelegate,
      routeInformationProvider: router.routeInformationProvider,
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(GoRouter.of(context).routeInformationProvider.value.location);

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            const Text("Page 1"),
            TextButton(
                onPressed: () => context.pushNamed(
                      RouteNames.anotherpage,
                      extra: 'arugment passed to next page',
                    ),
                child: const Text("Go to another page"))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AnotherPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const AnotherPage({super.key, required this.title});
  final String title;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(GoRouter.of(context).routeInformationProvider.value.location);
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(title),
            TextButton(
                onPressed: () => context.pop(),
                child: const Text("Previous Page"))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Routes File:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';
import 'package:test/main.dart';
import 'package:test/magic_string.dart';

class RouteGenerator {
  GoRouter router = GoRouter(
    debugLogDiagnostics: true,
    routes: [
      GoRoute(path: '/', builder: (context, state) => const HomePage()),
      GoRoute(
        name: RouteNames.anotherpage,
        path: '/${RouteNames.anotherpage}',
        pageBuilder: (context, state) {
          final args = state.extra! as String;
          return buildPageWithDefaultTransition<void>(
            context: context,
            state: state,
            child: AnotherPage(title: args),
          );
        },
      )
    ],
    errorPageBuilder: (context, state) =>
        const MaterialPage(child: ErrorRoute()),
  );
}

class ErrorRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  const ErrorRoute({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Error - 400"),
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: IconButton(
            icon: Platform.isIOS
                ? const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios)
                : const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_outlined),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
          ),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
        ),
      ),
      body: const Center(
        child: Text(
          "Page Not Found....",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

CustomTransitionPage buildPageWithDefaultTransition<T>({
  required BuildContext context,
  required GoRouterState state,
  required Widget child,
}) {
  return CustomTransitionPage<T>(
    key: state.pageKey,
    child: child,
    transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) =>
        ScaleTransition(scale: animation, child: child),
    //FadeTransition(opacity: animation, child: child),

///Can select between fade and scale, the two I normally use, can research for more transition types...
  );
}
```

Magic String file (A file with static variables- consists of the route names... helps not to make mistakes when rewriting the route names)

```
class RouteNames {
  static const String homepage = '/', anotherpage = 'page2';
}
```

[image]
[image]